# Documents not arriving in print queue - HP Driver issue

Tags: windows, drivers, printing, printer, hp-officejet

I have two hp wireless printers which worked fine until some days ago.

Now, my HP Officejet Pro 6830 has a strange issue. Even if it appears as installed both in the (new) windows 10 Printers & scanners dialogue, as well as in Control Panel > Devices and Printers, when I try to print, the print queue remains empty. Moreover, MS Word 2010 (after having selected the right printer and clicked on print) opens a pop-up telling me: "Word cannot print. There is no printer installed".

In CP > Devices and printers, if I right-click on the printer and on Properties, Win10 tells me: "The HP Officejet Pro printer driver is not installed on this computer... do you want to install now?". If I click 'yes', the driver seems to install correctly, and the wizard exits with success. However, if I try to print a test page, the system tells me: "test page failed to print" and suggests the use of the in-built troublesshooter. That one is not able to find any issue.

The HP Printer Assistant is working correctly, and I can connect via WIFI to the printer homepage.

I have tried uninstalling all HP software & drivers, but if I do that, on reinstall the installer is unable to connect to the printer and to register the printer with the OS, even if the software correctly detects the printer on the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue to be a corrupt driver file:

1. removed all HP devices through CP -> Devices and printers
2. uninstalled all hp software
3. cleaned registry, restart
4. Re-installed HP software. After TWO CONSECUTIVE failures of the installer to connect to the printer, the installer suggested to download and use a "HP Installation Failure" troubleshooter (link provided by the SW)
5. Followed instructions. Downloaded a HP Driver Repair Tool (link provided by SW - karnakredx_wsd_pqclean.exe) -> this one found and repaired issue with one of the driver files  (which seems to have survived un I nstall and reinstall of the hp drivers)
6. connected to printer without issue